# Simultaneity of events in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose light takes 8 minutes to reach  from sun to earth and an event takes place at the sun at t=0 in the frame of the sun and another event on earth at t=1 minute. Then how do i find the velocity of an inertial frame in which both the events will be simultaneous?

I tried using time dilation formula, but couldn't get to an appropriate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only good way to approach problems like this is to use the [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation). In the rest frame $S$ we have two events. We'll set the origin at the event on the Sun so its coordinates are $(t=0, x=0)$. Then the second event on the Earth is at $(t=T, x=D)$ where $T$ is one minute and $D$ is the Sun-Earth distance. Then in the frame $S'$ moving with velocity $v$ the Lorentz transformations tell us that:

$$\begin{align}
t' &= \gamma \left( t - \frac{vx}{c^2} \right ) \\
x' &= \gamma \left( x - vt \right)
\end{align}$$

The origin $(0,0)$ is the same in both frames, so to make the events simultaneous in $S'$ you need $t'=0$ i.e. for the Earth event:

$$ t' = \gamma \left( T - \frac{vD}{c^2} \right ) = 0 $$

Solve this to find the required value for the velocity $v$.

I can't emphasise strongly enough how important it is to approach problems like this in a disciplined manner. Start by defining the spacetime coordinates of the relevant events then use the Lorentz transformations to find the locations of those events in the boosted frame. That will give you the answer.

Students new to SR tend to wave factors of $\gamma$ around in the vague hope it will give the correct answer, but unless you really understand what you're doing this is unlikely to be useful. Assuming this is work that will be marked, your professor will expect you to show a rigorous approach i.e. using the Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 1):

I am using units where $c=1$.

$E_1=(0;0), E_2=(t;x)$ where $t=1$min, $x$=distance(sun,earth). Then

$E_1'=(0;0)$ and

$E_2'=(t',x')=\gamma(t-vx, x-vt)$

Now we want that $E_1'$ and $E_2'$ have the same time coordinate, so $t'=0$ and therefore $t-vx=0$ or $v=t/x$